# What advantages do JSF's h:outputScript/ h:outputStylesheet have over plain HTML script/style elements

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, resources

Is it preferable to use JSF's `h:outputScript` or `h:outputStylesheet` when `script`/`style` elements may just work for you ? What advantages does former offer over the latter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSF builtin resource handling has at least the following advantages:

- [Resource versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929417/jsf-resource-versioning)
- [Configurable cache control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389842/set-http-headers-properly-to-force-caching-on-js-css-and-png-files/18389932#18389932)
- [Packaging in JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code)
- [Programmatic (component based) manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768109/jsf2-static-resource-management-combined-compressed)
- [Automatic prepending of right context path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113436/js-files-not-referenced-in-the-application/)
- [EL support in CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700987/jsf-el-i18n-in-css-files/)
- i18n support (different resource files based on user's locale)
- Automatic HTTP/2 push (JSF 2.3+ on HTTPS only)

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: thanks for all the relevant links.. I want to clarify one thing though.. I make use of omnifaces `CombinedResourceHandler`. Would configuring cache setting using context-param `org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_MAX_TIME_EXPIRES` actually work ?

Answer (score 2):

Normal script/styles work if you know exactly under which context url the application is deployed.

So if you want to deploy the application under another context url you have to change your jsf code if you use script/style instead of h:outputScript and h:outputStylesheet.